# spark - Converting dataframe to list improving performance

Tags: python, performance, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to covert a column of the Spark dataframe to list to use later for matplotlib

```
df.toPandas()[col_name].values.tolist()
```

it looks like there is high performance overhead this operation takes around 18sec
is there other way to do that or improve the perfomance?

Comment: I guess that the performance overhead is rather in toPandas() as that's the first action in the chain.

Comment: @JiriS And what can I do about it?

Comment: How much data do you have in that one column? Spark has to send all the data for that one column to the driver (plus serialization/de-serialization overhead). Are you using kryo serialization? If not enable it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really need a local list there is not much you can do here but one improvement is to collect only a single column not a whole `DataFrame`:

```
df.select(col_name).flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

Comment: It didn't really helped me.Maybe something else could be done?

Comment: Other than dropping a whole idea? Not really. Why do you want a local list?

Comment: for matplotlib maybe there is some other way

Comment: Well, for starters you can double check your pipeline. Is there any reason to expect faster execution? Do you cache reused data? Other than that consider using smarter visualization techniques (sampling, bucketing, different methods of extrapolation, shading) which don't require full data. How much data do you collect right now?

Comment: A few months later you answered this question pointing out that flatMap is not supported on dataframe anymore https://stackoverflow.com/a/37225736/1335793

Answer (score 15):

You can do it this way:

```
>>> [list(row) for row in df.collect()]
```

Example:
`>>> d = [['Alice', 1], ['Bob', 2]]`
`>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(d, ['name', 'age'])`
`>>> df.show()`
`+-----+---+`
`| name|age|`
`+-----+---+`
`|Alice|  1|`
`|  Bob|  2|`
`+-----+---+`
`>>> to_list = [list(row) for row in df.collect()]`
`print list`
Result: `[[u'Alice', 1], [u'Bob', 2]]`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: You can use df.toLocalIterator() instead of df.collect() for superior performance as per @Artem Osipov's answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use an iterator to save memory `toLocalIterator`. The iterator will consume as much memory as the largest partition in this. And if you need to use the result only once, then the iterator is perfect is this case.

```
d = [['Bender', 12], ['Flex', 123],['Fry', 1234]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(d, ['name', 'value'])
df.show()
+------+-----+
|  name|value|
+------+-----+
|Bender|   12|
|  Flex|  123|
|   Fry| 1234|
+------+-----+`
values = [row.value for row in df.toLocalIterator()]

print(values)
>>> [12, 123, 1234]
```

Also toPandas() method should only be used if the resulting Pandas's DataFrame is expected to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver's memory.