# PySpark flatmap should return tuples with typed values

Tags: python, pyspark, namedtuple, flatmap

I'm using Jupyter Notebook with PySpark. Within that I have a have a dataframe that has a schema with column names and types (integer, ...) for those columns. Now I use methods like flatMap but this returns a list of tuples that have no fixed type anymore. Is there a way to achieve that?

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ...
 |-- ...
 |-- ratings: integer (nullable = true)
```

Then I use flatMap to do some calculations with the rating values (obfuscated here):

```
df.flatMap(lambda row: (row.id, 5 if (row.ratings > 5) else row.ratings))
y_rate.toDF().printSchema()
```

And now I get an error:

> TypeError: Can not infer schema for type:

Is there any way to use map/flatMap/reduce by keeping the schema? or at least returning tuples that have values of a specific type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you're using a wrong function. `flatMap` will `map` and `flatten` so assuming your data looks like this:

```
df = sc.parallelize([("foo", 0), ("bar", 10)]).toDF(["id", "ratings"])
```

output of the `flatMap` will be equivalent to:

```
sc.parallelize(['foo', 0, 'bar', 5])
```

Hence the error you see. If you really want to make it work you should use `map`:

```
df.rdd.map(lambda row: (row.id, 5 if (row.ratings > 5) else row.ratings)).toDF()
## DataFrame[_1: string, _2: bigint]
```

Next, mapping over `DataFrame` is no longer supported in 2.0. You should extract `rdd` first (see `df.rdd.map` above).

Finally passing data between Python and JVM is extremely inefficient. It not only requires passing data between Python and JVM with corresponding serialization / deserialization and schema inference (if schema is not explicitly provided) which also breaks laziness. It is better to use SQL expressions for things like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

df.select(df.id, when(df.ratings > 5, 5).otherwise(df.ratings))
```

If for some reason you need plain Python code an UDF could be a better choice.

Comment: Extremely helpful. thanks for your example code. I just didn't get the part with flatMap vs Map.

Comment: `flatMap` is a function `RDD[T] => (T => Iterable[U]) => RDD[U]`. In other words it expects function to return `Itereble` (Python tuple is) and concatenates these (flattens) the result.

Comment: Is there a way to give the when/otherwise column a name in that statement? see `df.select(df.id, when(df.ratings > 5, 5).otherwise(df.ratings))` @zero323

Comment: Yes, you can use `alias` for example: `when(df.ratings > 5, 5).otherwise(df.ratings).alias("foo")`.