# pyspark dataframe to dictionary: columns as keys and list of column values ad dict value

Tags: python, pyspark

Hi i have an requirement of converting a pyspark dataframe (or rdd) into a dictionary where column of dataframe will be keys and column_value_list as dictionary values.

```
name amt
a    10
b    20
a    30
b    40
c    50
```

i want a dictionary like this:

```
new_dict = {'name':['a','b', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'amt':[10,20,30,40,50]}
```

How can I do that, (avoiding collect on rdd is preferable solution). Thanks.

I am also trying, will post my try in some time.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your spark dataframe into a pandas dataframe with the `.toPandas` method, then use pandas's `.to_dict` method to get your dictionary:

```
new_dict = spark_df.toPandas().to_dict(orient='list')
```

#### Edit:

I am not aware of a way to make a dictionary out an `rdd` or `spark df` without collecting the values. You can use the `.collectAsMap` method of your `rdd` without the need to convert the data in a dataframe first:

```
rdd.collectAsMap()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Abdou-it helps, but to_pandas will collect the data to master node when called on a spark-cluster. I really want to avoid that. Is there a way(map on rdd or something) where there will be no collect happens. I am dealing with a huge dataset actually(10 million rows appx.).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it like this (python 3.x, pyspark 2.x):

```
def columnDict(dataFrame):
    colDict = dict(zip(dataFrame.schema.names, zip(*dataFrame.collect())))
    return colDict if colDict else dict.fromkeys(dataFrame.schema.names, ())
```

If you want to have a python dictionary, you have to collect it first. If you don´t want to collect, you could manually create a dictionary with selected and mapped RDDs

```
colDict[col_name] = dataFrame.select(col_name).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)
```

Like in this solution: [spark - Converting dataframe to list improving performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364133/spark-converting-dataframe-to-list-improving-performance).